# Split pattern output by spaces in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, split

I need to extract the third column of a string returned after matching a Pattern.
It also needs to be a one-liner

File contains data like this:

```
f5834eab44ff bfd0bc8498d8 1557718920
dc8087c38a0d a72e89879030 1557691221
e6d7aaf6d76b caf6cd0ef68c 1557543565
```

Right now it matches the pattern and returns the line.
But I cannot get it to Split on the spaces so I can get the 3rd column (index 2).

```bsh
    select-string -Path $hashlistfile -Pattern 'dc8087c38a0d') | $_.Split(" ") | $_[2]
```

Output should be:

```
1557691221
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the `Line` property from the output object produced by `Select-String`, split that and then index directly into the result of `String.Split()`:

```
Select-String -Path $hashlistfile -Pattern dc8087c38a0d |ForEach-Object {
  $_.Line.Split(" ")[2]
}
```

Comment: @elcool You were also missing the `ForEach-Object`. `... | $_.Split()` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use '$_' inside cmdlets that have a script block option '{ }'.  Select-string returns MatchInfo objects.

```
(select-string dc8087c38a0d $hashlistfile).gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    MatchInfo                                System.Object
```

The -split operator seems to deal with it more easily.  There's an extra parenthesis ')' after the pattern in your example.

```
select-string dc8087c38a0d $hashlistfile | foreach { -split $_ | select -index 2 }

1557691221
```